Android recyclerview paging
Attempting recyclerview paging.
I expected scrolling to load the text, but just when I run the app, all the information is loaded, what's wrong with the code?
inner class PostPagingSource : PagingSource<String, Post>(){
        override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<String>) : LoadResult<String, Post>{
            try{
                Log.d("Paging", "Loading page with key: ${params.key}")
                val query = if (params.key == null){
                    postRef.orderByKey().limitToFirst(params.loadSize)
                } else {
                    postRef.orderByKey().startAfter(params.key).limitToFirst(params.loadSize)
                }
                val snapshot = query.get().await()
                val posts = snapshot.children.mapNotNull { it.getValue(Post::class.java) }
                Log.d("Paging", "Loaded ${posts.size} posts")
                return LoadResult.Page(
                    data = posts,
                    prevKey = null,
                    nextKey = snapshot.children.lastOrNull()?.key
                )
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                return LoadResult.Error(e)
                Log.e("Paging", "Error loading page: ${e.message}")
            }
        }

        override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<String, Post>): String? {
            val position = state.anchorPosition ?: return null
            val closestPage = state.closestPageToPosition(position)
            return closestPage?.nextKey
        }

    }



val postsFlow = Pager(
        config = PagingConfig(
            pageSize = 4,
            initialLoadSize = 4,
            enablePlaceholders = false
        ),
        pagingSourceFactory = { repository.PostPagingSource() }
    ).flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)


2024-11-30 15:11:37.606  6897-6897  Paging Loaded 4 posts
2024-11-30 15:11:37.661  6897-6897  Paging Loading page with key: post4
2024-11-30 15:11:37.706  6897-6897  Paging Loaded 1 posts
2024-11-30 15:11:37.707  6897-6897  Paging Loading page with key: post5
2024-11-30 15:11:37.713  6897-6897  Paging Loaded 0 posts

It loads all data at once.
I tried to change initialLoadSize config but it can't change the result.
